# Clear Selection when TableView loses focus

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, tableview, javafx-8

I'm trying to clear the selection when my table view loses focus. Right now, when I click on my add button, a new EMPTY row is added and I set it so the first column is on edit. If I click anywhere outside that cell, nothing happens. The cell remains selected which is not really what I want.
I'd prefer for the cell to become unselected when my tableview is unfocused.

I use a `javafx.scene.control.TableView` over a custom entry. 
I tried setting on each column a `setOnEditCancel` but it doesn't work.

```
    expressionTableColumn.setOnEditCancel(event -> {
            final ObservableList<TableEntry> items = tableView.getItems();
            if (items.contains(EMPTY_ENTRY)) {
                items.remove(EMPTY_ENTRY);
            }
            tableView.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
        }

    );
```

I'd prefer to clearSelection on table losing focus. Any ideas?

Comment: Create a sample app that duplicates what you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `ChangeListener` to the [`focused` property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#focusedProperty) of `Node` (which `TableView` inherits). Then, when the new value of said property is `false`, retrieve the `SelectionModel` from the `TableView`'s [`selectionModel` property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#selectionModelProperty) and call [`clearSelection()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/SelectionModel.html#clearSelection()).

```
tableView.focusedProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
    if (!newVal) {
        tableView.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
    }
});
```

Comment: this doesn't work either. It doesn't do anything when I unfocus the table

Comment: @Mocktheduck Having just tried this I can confirm this works as advertised. If this doesn't work for you please add a [mcve] to your question as Sedrick suggests. You could also check the `TableView` is _actually_ losing focus via the [`focusOwner` property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#focusOwnerProperty) of `Scene`.